# Views in play-framework 2.1 not handling javascript

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I've come into a wall : Basically, Javascript doesn't seem to be working in my play pages.

So I have a view `main.scala.html` as a template for other views.
This file looks like that :

```
@(page : String, title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--some stuff-->
@content
</body>
</html>
```

So I tried putting a simple `<a href="#" onclick="alert('thing')">thing</a>` in the body of the views.

-First in the main.scala.html template

-Then in a view that used this template

-Finally in a thing.html, with no links what so ever with Play! Framework, that I opened in my browser:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('truc')">truc</a>
</body>
```

Only the third option return the wanted result : A popup with `thing` in it.

My question is : Why is my javascript not handled by play? Do I have to "`import`" some global javascript feature in order to use it?

Thanks for your help, if you need more info, tell me.

Comment: Your `main` template looks fine, have you put the javascript in `/public/javascripts` and do you have the following line in your routes: `GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)` ?

Comment: I do have the route `GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`, and my javascripts are in the `/public/javascripts` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play produces normal HTML code - browser doesn't care what kind of soft produced it, so I suspect, that you have some mistake in path to some JS file in your head, so it avoids running other scripts, Use some kind of inspector in your browser, to validate, that all resources are downloaded properly. Also check JS console, most probably there are some errors shown.

On the other hand, placing simple JS directly in the views most often works correctly, however, keep in mind that, view's renderer may consider some JS typical syntax as a Play's tag, or something, therefore you need to control still if after rendering your JS is not 'damaged' by this process. For views where you want to use more advanced JS it's absolutely safer (and more comfortable) to include JS from static file(s) the same way as you are using for `jquery.js` or `bootstrap.js`

Comment: It was a problem with CSP. Thanks for the JS console advice.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to write

```
@main(title = "my title") {
 <h1>Other html<h1>
 <p>My js here</p>
 <a href="#" onclick="alert('truc')">truc</a>
}
```

P.S:
If it is helpfull don't forget that you shouldn't white **head** , **html** and **body** tags any more, it is included already. Otherwise you will have not valid html, and it will render bad in all browsers

Comment: It was a problem with a CSP blocking the javascript. But thanks !
PS : Be careful, you can get rid of the **head**, **body**, and **html** tags ONLY if you already declared it in the main template.
What you proposed would have been relevant if I used js in a view that used the main template, but here, i'm declaring the main template, so I need to write these tags !